# Dynamically create a NSString stringWithFormat: output

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

trying to figure out how to add zeroes in front of a random generated number with dynamic length of the number.
For example if the number is 10 characters long, I can print the number as   stringWithFormat:@"%.10d",i

Since the numer can somtimes be shorter than maximum length, it needs zeroes to fill the maximum length of the number to fit the string.

```
- (void)method:(int)length{
int i = rand() % length;
NSLog (@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.'length'd",i]);
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
NSLog (@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%010d",i]);
```

The meaning of format string components:

- 1st 0 - means that the number must be padded to specific width with zeros
- 10 - required minimum width of output

For more information about format specifiers you can check this [printf specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html). I sometimes also use this [shorter one](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) - you can find your example there.

You can create your format string dynamically as well - you'll need to calculate maximum number length in advance (maxLength in example):

```
NSString* format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%0%dd", maxLength];
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:format, 10];
NSLog(@"%@", s);
```

Comment: Thanks for the format specifier info.
But the dynamic length still remains a question. Is it possible to get the required minimum width of the output to be dynamic depending on the maximum length of the number that should be padded?
Example result
max_length 1000 (4 digits) - result 0042
max_length 100000 (6 digits) - result 003491

Comment: +1 for the links to compact + detailed printf specifications. I struggled to find them via google, but found them easily with your answer - thanks!